# Arrow in case statement supported from Java 14 onwards only Java compilation error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, switch-statement

I am new to Java. I am using Eclipse IDE, using the following config:

```
java.runtime.name=OpenJDK Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version=16.0.1+9-24
```

I do have simple switch statement:

```
 var forecastedAmount = amount * switch (dealStage) {
            case LEAD -> 0.2;
            case EVALUATING -> 0.5;
            case INTERESTED -> 0.8;
            case CLOSED -> 1;
        };
```

But I get compilation error as:

*Arrow in case statement supported from Java 14 onwards only*

Why is that?

Comment: Did you check the project's language level?

Comment: Actually in the project properties, in the Build Path I've changed to JRE 16 and indeed it compiles. Thanks! But one more thing pls: I see long list of JRE versions I can choose from, but actually I remember I have installed only 1 or 2 versions.. so where are all the others coming from? From Eclipse installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capturing my earlier comment as an answer for future reference: You should check the project properties and make sure you're using Java 16 in the build path.

Comment: I have the same problem (Eclipse 2023-12) but none of the answers seem to help.
[![Project settings][1]][1]
[![Compiler Preferences][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/78wEx.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBxZk.png

Comment: @Jörg please post a new question for this, it's really difficult to follow in the comments of the another question

Comment: OK, next time I have such a problem with stackoverflow, I will ask a new question. While I am not a stackoverflow expert, I am a Java expert and my problem is long solved. I somehow just wanted to help others by sharing further problem details to the same error and according learnings. But during my day I am now already 10 problems ahead and sorry if I was using stackoverflow not in the way it is meant to be.

Answer (score 3):

Check the JDK Compliance setting in Eclipse (Window -> Preferences > Java > Compiler).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).